# Running a portion of Python code in parallel on two different GPUs

Tags: python, gpu, pytorch

I have a PyTorch script similar to the following:

```
# Loading data
train_loader, test_loader = someDataLoaderFunction()

# Define the architecture
model = ResNet18()
model = model.cuda()  

# Get method from program argument
method = args.method

# Training
train(method, model, train_loader, test_loader)
```

In order to run the script with two different methods (`method1` and `method2`), it suffices to run the following commands in two different terminals:

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python program.py --method method1
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 python program.py --method method2
```

The problem is, the above data loader function contains some **randomness** in it, which means that the two methods were applied to two different sets of training data. I would like them to train the exact same set of data, so I modified the script as follows:

```
# Loading data
train_loader, test_loader = someDataLoaderFunction()

# Define the architecture
model = ResNet18()
model = model.cuda()  

## Run for the first method
method = 'method1'

 # Training
train(method, model, train_loader, test_loader)

## Run for the second method
method = 'method2'

# Must re-initialize the network first
model = ResNet18()
model = model.cuda()

 # Training
train(method, model, train_loader, test_loader)
```

Is it possible to make it run in parallel for each method?
Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Comment: Umm, parallel computing would need different coding architecture altogether, have you done any before? The least I can do is point you towards the `queue` inbuilt lib in Python 3, you must use it to orchestrate the parallel execution. Also please read about race conditions and thread locking, otherwise you may end up in coding frustration

Comment: @aim100k Thanks. I only did some basic stuffs like parallel for loops in C++ or Matlab :(

Comment: I saw your website, and I think what you are doing is really awesome. I also love those subjects but can't afford that much education. Anyway, hope you find an answer here

Comment: @aim100k Thanks anyway! P/s: if you’re talking about financial issue: education in Europe is almost free. If you are interested I can give you some information on Master/PhD opportunities here in France.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the easiest way would be to fix the seeds as below.

```
myseed=args.seed
np.random.seed(myseed)
torch.manual_seed(myseed)
torch.cuda.manual_seed(myseed)
```

This should force the data loaders to get the same samples every time. The parallel way is to use multithreading but I hardly see it worth the hassle for the problem you posted.

Comment: Thanks. I got the same answer here: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-run-two-training-methods-in-parallel-on-exactly-the-same-data/7796/2